# Visual Studio Post Build Event Unable to access appsettings or webconfig

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have the following code.

I am doing this in the post build event, the below class is getting executed but it is unable to make any access to appsettings.

I tried all combinations like giving absolute path and accessing through configurationmanager, but nothing worked.

The below class is inside the project where we have web.config and appsettings.

Can you please tell me what can be the issue.

```
TestResources:AppDomainIsolatedTask
{
       private NameValueCollection constants = (NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("applicationSettings/applicationConstants");

       public override bool Execute()
       {
          constants.Get("VersionNo")
       }        

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
        var fileMap = new System.Configuration.ExeConfigurationFileMap { ExeConfigFilename = "path to config" };
        var config = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        var section = (NameValueCollection)config.GetSection("name of section");
```

Comment: @miyamot , do i need to to give absolute web.config path in that pathtoconfig.

Comment: @miyamot i get this error: error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'System
onfiguration.ConfigurationSection' to 'System.Collections.Specialized.NameVal
Collection'

Comment: in name of section i am giving following applicationSettings/applicationConstants

Comment: @gov - Can you edit your question to include the config. Namely the <configSections> ... </configSections> and the <applicationSettings> ... </applicationSettings>?

Comment: it finally worked , i did the following NameValueCollection nRet = new NameValueCollection();
                System.Xml.XmlDocument xDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
                string sXml = section.SectionInformation.GetRawXml();                
                xDoc.LoadXml(sXml);

                NameValueCollection nameValueCollections = (NameValueCollection)(new NameValueSectionHandler()).Create(null, null, xDoc.FirstChild);

Comment: @miyamotogl, you gave me the right direction , thanks i tried hit and trial but finally it worked, but i got clue only after your code once again thanks a lot.

Comment: @miyamo , i marked your as answer , once again big thanks for clearing my blocker.

Comment: @gov - You should investigate using a strongly type configuration class if you need a more robust solution. You will be able to access the values using the object's properties rather than a string key. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx

Comment: I think that is in part why my example did not work (the first error CS0030).  I tacked on the cast to (NameValueCollection).  I was previously casting to a class inheriting from ConfigurationSection.  Sorry for not debugging before posting my answer :/.

Comment: @miya no problem , the direction is enough.